# Simple HTML and CSS background repeat

Tags: php, html, css

My website is http://nickliddell.com/pieres.

As you can see, the background on the header is repeating. I tried adding `background-repeat:no-repeat;` to all of the divs that is in the header, and it is still repeating.
Here is my header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
 global $cubby_options;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>
<?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?>
</title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<center>
<div class="header">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contact left">
        <?php  echo cubby_options_array('top_contact_info') ; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="follow right"> <?php echo cubby_get_social_network(array("skype","facebook",'twitter','google_plus','youtube',"linkedin",'pinterest','rss'));?> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="top2">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo left"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
        <?php if ( cubby_options_array('logo')!="") { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo cubby_options_array('logo'); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <span class="site-name">
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
        </span>
        <?php }?>
        </a><span class="tagline"><?php echo  get_bloginfo( 'description' );?></span></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_bottom">
    <?php do_action('wp_menubar','Home'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</center>
<!--header-->
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
.top2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    min-height:186px;
    background:#cccccc;
    padding:20px 0 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.top {
    height:20px;
    background:#333333;
    padding:5px 0;
    color:#ccc;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
    min-height:60px
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.top2 .menu_bottom{
    display: block;
    position: absolute:
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -20px
}
.header {
    }.center-content,.footer {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Sorry I'm new to html and css. I was also wondering, how come in the stylesheet it states the classes as having a color as a background, but on the page it shows the image?
All replies are appreciated :)

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code, so that it stills shows your problem but is easier for us to read?

Comment: If this is actual a snip from you code, you should go thru it. Because I guess not everything is working like you wanted. You have `min-height:60px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat;` Without any elements linked to it. Also, use `margin: 0 auto;` - this will do that same as `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Well check your code. Because you have this:

```
    .header .top2 {
url("http://www.nickliddell.com/pieres/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cropped-header1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Where it says repeat. Change it to:

```
.header .top2 {
    background-image: url("http://www.nickliddell.com/pieres/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cropped-header1.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also, if you are new. Do like what I typed in, and it will be easier for you to see the mistake ;)

Comment: Where do you see ".header .top2" ?

Comment: Its in your one of your .php files. Its not in any of your css files. So I would guess, inside a `<style></style>` at index.php or (single.php(?)) maybe.